# How to create a 2 column menu list in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to create a menu list of image buttons, similar to the homescreen list, or the collection list in XBOXLive games app. Not sure what type of controls I need to use and how to structure them for a vertically scrolling list of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retemplate a `ListBox` (or similar) but it's probably simpler (you decide) to put the items in a `WrapPanel` (from the [silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291)) inside a `ScrollViewer`.

This example uses buttons but you could use images or anything:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <toolkit:WrapPanel>
            <Button Width="200" Height="200" Content="option1"/>
            <Button Width="200" Height="200" Content="option2"/>
            <Button Width="200" Height="200" Content="option3"/>
            <Button Width="200" Height="200" Content="option4"/>
            <Button Width="200" Height="200" Content="option5"/>
            <Button Width="200" Height="200" Content="option6"/>
            <Button Width="200" Height="200" Content="option7"/>
            <Button Width="200" Height="200" Content="option8"/>
            <Button Width="200" Height="200" Content="option9"/>
        </toolkit:WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**N.B.** Actually, after testing the above, you probably don't want buttons and you'll need to be careful about selecting images while scrolling.